# Integral of a cross-correlated Gaussian distribution over the first octant.

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Let $d\ge 2$ be an integer and let ${\bf c}:=\left( c_{i,j} \right)_{1\le i < j \le d}$. Consider a following integral:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}^{(d)}({\bf c}) := \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}_+^d} \exp\left( -\sum\limits_{i=1}^d x_i^2 - 2\sum\limits_{1\le i < j \le d} x_i x_j c_{i,j}\right) \prod\limits_{i=1}^d d x_i
\end{equation}

By generalizing the approach in [Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+y^2+2xy \cos \theta)} \,dx dy = \frac{\theta}{2\sin\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083318/prove-that-int-0-infty-int-0-infty-e-x2y22xy-cos-theta-dx) meaning by completing the quadratic form in the exponential to a square and then by going to polar coordinates we have computed the result in three dimensions. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathcal I}^{(3)}({\bf c}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{{\mathcal D}}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\left( \frac{\pi}{2} +\right.\\
&&\left.-\arcsin\left(\frac{c_{2,3}-c_{1,2} c_{1,3}}{\sqrt{c_{1,2}^2 c_{1,3}^2-c_{1,2}^2-c_{1,3}^2+1}}\right)+\right.\\
&&\left.-\arcsin\left(\frac{c_{1,3}-c_{1,2} c_{2,3}}{\sqrt{c_{1,2}^2
   c_{2,3}^2-c_{1,2}^2-c_{2,3}^2+1}}\right)+\right.\\
&&\left.-\arcsin\left(\frac{c_{1,2}-c_{1,3} c_{2,3}}{\sqrt{c_{1,3}^2 c_{2,3}^2-c_{1,3}^2-c_{2,3}^2+1}}\right)
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

where 
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal D} &:=& 1-c_{1,2}^2-c_{1,3}^2-c_{2,3}^2+2 c_{1,2} c_{2,3} c_{1,3}\\
\end{eqnarray}

As a sanity check we analyze the case when the cross-correlations vanish. 
Here all three arc sin terms vanish and the result equals $\pi^{3/2}/8$ as it should be.

Now, my question would be how do I compute the result for arbitary values of $d$.

Comment: In general $\mathcal{I}^{d}$ is related to the volume of certain $(d-1)$-dimensional orthoscheme on the sphere $S^{d-1}$. When $d=3$ they are expressible in terms of inverse trigonometric functions using spherical trigonometry, but already when $d=4$ you need more intricate formulas such as Schläfli formula which involves dilogarithms.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee: Thanks for that. I would love to see the result for generic $d$ . This result can also have a probabilistic interpretation.  For example in the realm of stochastic processes ${\mathcal I}^{(d)}$ would be related to the likelihood that $d$ consecutive returns of a fractional Brownian Noise are all positive. This in turn could be used to deriving the distribution of drawdowns in such a process.

Comment: @SangchulLee is right when he says "intricate".  Look at "SPHERICAL SIMPLICES AND THEIR POLARS" by 
Kenzi Satô, *The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*, Volume 58, Issue 1, 1 March 2007, Pages 107–126, https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/hal008 and references therein, for an overview.